# Celery: list all tasks, scheduled, active *and* finished

Tags: celery, celery-task

**Update for the bounty**

I'd like a solution that does not involve a monitoring thread, if possible.

---

I know I can view *scheduled* and *active* tasks using the `Inspect` class of my apps `Control`.

```
i = myapp.control.inspect()

currently_running = i.active()
scheduled = i.scheduled()
```

But I could not find any function to show already finished tasks. I know that this information mus be at least temporarily accessible, because I can look up a finished task by its `task_id`:

```
>>> r = my task.AsyncResult(task_id=' ... ')
>>> r.state
u'SUCCESS'
```

How can I get a *complete* list of scheduled, active and finished tasks? Or possibly a list of *all* tasks at once?

Comment: I agree that the information is retrivable. I use flower and the flower application can retrive the state of all the tasks. I find that there is a cache dictionary in the backend, but only stores a few tasks `myapp.backend._cache`. Flower has a restful api, I think that you can use that in your web monitoring application, but It must be another way...

Answer (score 10):

[Celery Flower](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) shows tasks (active, [finished](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/tasks.png), reserved, etc) in real time. It enables to filter tasks by time, workers and types.

https://github.com/mher/flower

Comment: I'm required to integrate a monitoring solution within a website, so unfortunately I cannot use an out-of-the box solution like flower. But I'll look into it anyways, since it supports my assumption, that the information is indeed retrievable. So thanks for the hint. +1

Comment: Check out how it is implemented in flower or use flower api

Comment: I am trying to solve puzzle of where tasks info is stored... I can browse 2000 completed tasks in Flower but the redis dbs configured as broker and result backend are both empty (no keys)... I thought I should see something there?

Comment: Flower stores them in memory - if you restart it, all (at least all finished) tasks are gone.

Answer (score 2):

One option not requiring a monitoring thread is a Celery `on_success` handler (using bootsteps feature [in 3.1+](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whatsnew-3.1.html#bootsteps-extending-the-worker)) - this would need to write relevant info to your own datastore.

- You need to create a [custom task class](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes) to do this. This [on_failure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223998/python-celery-retrieve-tasks-arguments-if-theres-an-exception) gives an idea.

Possibly better option, needing less code, is to use a [task_success signal](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-success) in a similar way, recording the info you need later.

The Flower option is probably simpler, as you are querying info already maintained by Flower when tasks complete - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32859547/992887).