# Python celery: Retrieve tasks arguments if there's an exception

Tags: python, exception, celery

I am getting started with Celery and Python, and I have a question that is probably very simple, but I don't seem to be able to find any suitable answer around...

If I have a bunch of tasks, and one of them throws, an exception, is there a way of retrieving the arguments that were passed to said task?

For instance, if I want to get the IPs some hostnames resolve to, and I create a task...

```
@tasks_app.task
def resolve_hostname(hostname):
    return (hostname, {hst.address for hst in dns.resolver.query(hostname)})
```

... which can throw an exception, is there a way of getting the value of that `hostname` argument outside the call when that Exception happens?

Let's say I group the tasks like:

```
ip_subtasks = group(
    resolve_hostname.s(hostname) for hostname in ['google.com',
                                                  'yahoo.com',
                                                  'failure.kommm']
)()
```

The last one (that tries to resolve `failure.kommm` ) will raise an exception. I'd like to put the `get()` method of the celery task inside a `try/catch`, and show a message saying *Something went wrong when trying to resolve failure.kommm* (something like shown below):

```
for ip_subtask in ip_subtasks:
    try:
        hostname, ips = ip_subtask.get(timeout=45)
    except dns.exception.DNSException, e:
        # I WISHED THIS WORKED:
        logger.exception("Something happened when trying"
                         " to resolve %s" % ip_subtask.args[0])
```

So, that's the question... Is there a way of retrieving the arguments a task was executed with if I have the task instance itself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at an `on_failure` handler? http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#on_failure

Comment: I have, and I think it would work, but I don't know how to use it when the task has been created through a decorator like shown above (as I said, I'm a newbie with Celery)

Comment: Check out the section above handlers, it shows you how to do just that with an abstract class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do this you can use an [abstract class](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#abstract-classes) to implement an [`on_failure`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#on_failure) handler.

```
from celery import Task

class DebugTask(Task):
    abstract = True

    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        logger.exception("Something happened when trying"
                         " to resolve %s" % args[0])

@tasks_app.task(base=DebugTask)
def resolve_hostname(hostname):
    return (hostname, {hst.address for hst in dns.resolver.query(hostname)})
```

From the docs:

```
on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

Parameters: 
  exc     – The exception raised by the task.
  task_id – Unique id of the failed task.
  args    – Original arguments for the task that failed.
  kwargs  – Original keyword arguments for the task that failed.
  einfo   – ExceptionInfo instance, containing the traceback.
```

Comment: on_failure doesn't catch TimeLimitException.

Comment: The section of docs immediately following the one linked for `on_failure` describes how to use a custom Request to handle `on_timeout` with a pre-forking worker. Otherwise that should be handled by you in the task itself

Comment: what is the difference between on_failure (in Task and Request) and on_timeout?