# How can I get a list of succeeded Celery task ids?

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Celery with RabbitMQ as broker and backend.  I understand that I can use the following to get a list of scheduled tasks:

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
i = inspect()
i.scheduled()
```

But how can I get a list of task ids that have run and succeeded? (I've seen that Flower can help do this, but think it's inefficient to require another package to extract this information - unless it's only stored in RabbitMQ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery: list all tasks, scheduled, active \*and\* finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300374/celery-list-all-tasks-scheduled-active-and-finished)

Comment: Saw that post but seems inefficient to install another package just for the purpose of calling Celery?  Wouldn't this be something that Celery could do on its own?